# Document belonging to multiple tags/topics

Tags: discussion, tags, documentation, documentation-topics

This question is on the new Documentation section on Stack Overflow.

Sometimes examples for one tag could also be included in other tags. For example, a document example showing how to create different scopes using `spring` could be under either the `java` tag or the `spring` tag.

An example could belong to multiple topics too. For example, a document demonstrating how to create a `typedef`'d `struct` in `C` could be under the `typedef` topic or the `struct` topic.

What would be the suggested way of solving this type of problem?

Does Stack Overflow Documentation allow sharing between tags/topics (now or future)?

Comment: I guess now not, but in the future they may. I mean, if they have multiple languages code sections planned, then surely multiple tags might come in handy too.

Comment: Besides "examples for tag [that] could also be included in other tags", some topics may be about using multiple things (corresponding to tags) together. These topics are unlikely to be well-covered by official docs for each thing separately, so that's where SO docs could really add some value, but we would again need multiple tags to apply to a topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will add one example.

[GSON topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/4158/gson) inside Android tag and [gson](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/gson) tag. Both are related to same thing. Still they are separate and inconsistent.

IMO, making an example as separate entity will help. In different topics we can just embed an example from another tag. We can add additional comment as well.

For example gson may add some feature which is applicable to java 8 but not to android. Then we can simply embed examples that are applicable to android.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that finding documentation via tags can be more helpfull than finding documentation via current topic because a code-example can have more than topic.

Example: when i am interested in code-examples for android asynctask i will get

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/117/asynctask/14069/pass-activity-as-weakreference-to-avoid-memory-leaks
  https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/117/asynctask/5377/possible-problems-with-inner-async-tasks
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/2687/common-memory-leaks-and-how-to-avoid-them/9248/avoid-leaking-activities-with-asynctask

but i will miss

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/2687/common-memory-leaks-and-how-to-avoid-them/9248/avoid-leaking-activities-with-asynctask that is below a different topic.

If there where tags for examples i would have found all 3