# How to add the same example to 2 different topics on 2 different tags

Tags: discussion, tags, documentation, documentation-topics

If I am writing an example for a topic and I find another example, on another topic, of a different tag .. how do I include that example on my topic or add my tag to the topic?

For instance, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsoup/515/selectors/11336/extract-twitter-markup#t=201607271421512170151

This example is on the `Jsoup` documentation.  However, the example would be useful to include it on a topic on the `Open Graph` documentation.

There doesn't seem to be a clean way to do this without simply creating an example on `Open Graph` with just a hyperlink to the example on `Jsoup`.

Comment: ... Use a hyperlink?

Comment: Having a Documentation example with just a link doesn't provide any value.  However, being able to tag an example with both "jsoup" and "open graph" and the example shows up on both Documentation sites would be valuable.

Comment: Well, you just said "link the two together", so it seemed the obvious answer. In your case, someone's already asked about this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328705/215552

Comment: Do you mean two different tags? Topics reside within the same tag.

Comment: I revised the question for clarity.  It was confusing how I first asked it.

Comment: I am having the same question, [GSON topic][1] inside Android tag and [gson][2] tag on SO documentation. Both are related to same thing.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/4158/gson
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/gson